# Laravel - Relationship for belongsToMany and relationship for last belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, relationship

How can I go about getting the last entry in my belongsToMany relationship?

I have a model Offer and a model Status

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    /**
     * The statuses that the offer belongs to.
     */
    public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Status')->withPivot('user_id');
    }

    /**
     * The current status for the offer.
     */
    public function currentStatus()
    {
        return $this->statuses->last();
    }
}
```

But `currentStatus()` does not work.

I get `Call to undefined method App\Models\Status::addEagerConstraints()` when i do `Offer::first()->with('currentStatus');`

I've tried all sorts of stuff:

```
public function currentStatus()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Status')->withPivot('user_id')->latest();
}
```

and

```
public function latestMailLog()
{    
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\MailLog')->latest('id');
}
```

etc.

I don't even know if it's possible to do this.
But I've done something similar with

```
public function mailLogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MailLog');
}

public function latestMailLog()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\MailLog')->latest('id');
}
```

That isn't a many to many relationship though..

Any help would be appreciated :o)

Comment: Try like this `Offer::with('statuses')->first()->currentStatus();`; if you eager-load the `statuses` relationship, then access `currentStatus()` as a Method (with the `()`), then it should work. Can't speak to that error though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an auto increment primary key column `id` on the `offer_status` pivot table

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOfferStatusTable extends Migration
{
    Schema::create('offer_status', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreignId('offer_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('status_id')->constrained();

        $table->index(['offer_id', 'status_id]);
    });
}
```

Create a Pivot model called OfferStatus. You can make use of artisan command

```sh
php artisan make:model OfferStatus -p
```

OrderStatus.php will be created in `app/Models` directory

```php
class OfferStatus extends Pivot
{
    public $incrementing = true;
}
```

Now in the Offer model class tweak the relation for statuses and currentStatus.

And define a scope to get the dynamic relation currentStatus working

```php
/**class Offer extends Model
{
    /**
     * The statuses that the offer belongs to.
     */
    public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Status')
            ->withPivot('user_id')
            ->using(OfferStatus::class);
    }

    /**
     * The current status for the offer.
     */
    public function currentStatus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OfferStatus::class);
    }

    /**
     * Scope to make the dynamic relation currentStatus work
     */
    public function scopeWithCurrentStatus($query)
    {
        $query->addSelect(['current_status_id' => OfferStatus::select('id')
            ->whereColumn('offer_id', 'offers.id')
            ->latest()
            ->take(1)
        ])->with('currentStatus');
    }
}
```

Then you can access it as

```php
$offers = Offer::withCurrentStatus()->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't seem to eagerLoad currentStatus when doing it like this. `$offers = Offer::with('statuses')->with('currentStatus')->get();`I get the following error: `Call to undefined method App\Models\Status::addEagerConstraints()`

Comment: Of course you can't eager load currentStatus as it does not return a relationship. You will have to use it as a method on the offer object as in the answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I need it to eager load or else i can't use it in my specific use case. But thank you :)

Comment: @Nissen Have updated the answer to use dynamic relation, pls check and let me know if it works for you